# Как в jsoup отформатировать все теги и оставить только текст?

Tags: java, jsoup

Что имеется:

```
try {
      Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.yandex.ru/").get();
      Element kursUSD = doc.select(".inline-stocks__value_inner").first();
      System.out.println("Курс доллара на текущий момент - " + kursUSD);
```

Консоль мне выводит это:
`<span class="inline-stocks__value_inner">64,33</span>`

Как сделать так, что бы он мне выводил просто текст, без всяких тегов?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы выводите весь элемент, со всеми его атрибутами и контентом.
Для получения только текста, который содержится в теге, требуется вызвать метод:

```
kusrUSD.text();
```

Comment: Так просто, блин) Знал про этот text, но забыл его добавить.